# Can Chrysalid turn a MEC unit into a zombie

Tags: xcom-enemy-within

I'm just wondering.

If a Chrysalid attacks a MEC trooper and kills him/her, does the MEC trooper turn into a zombie? Does he/she turn into a mechanized zombie? Or does nothing special happen at all?

My web searches have turned up at best speculations.

Comment: I sincerely hope not.

Comment: I was under impression that they simply explode presumably leaving any remaining biological parts useless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Chrysalids are incapable of turning a MEC trooper into a zombie. They are unable to be implanted.